# Getting dashboard name using javascript in MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a standard way to get the current Dashboard name using the Dynamics javascript SDK ?

Comment: I doubt that, whats your use case?

Comment: I have an Angular webressource, which is shown on multiple dashboards, and show different data depending on the dashboard.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: It is how we do it currently, but it is far from ideal. And it is currently affected by a bug, which prevent it from working in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Custom Parameter(data)` under `Web Resource Properties` to send the Dashboard differentiating flag, parse the querystring & achieve what you want in web resource. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/sample-pass-multiple-values-web-resource-through-data-parameter)

> [image]

Comment: Is there any way to get it without having to pass a custom parameter ?

Comment: @Dremor not that I'm aware of. whats the bug you're talking about?

Comment: When using the "refresh all" button on the dashboard, the custom parameters are not sent to the webressource. The bug have been reported to MS and is awaiting resolution. In the meantime, I was searching for a way to directly get the dashboard name.